# Access db 2013 is there any agent to schedule jobs?

Tags: ms-access

I'm doing one social project and use only Acess/Office 2013 available, and trying to send email reminders for some event based on calculated column [Due_date] -[Today] < 10 days, my customers most likely won't open Access every day, so I'm wandering if any option exists in Access to schedule this job/check let say every 8am ?    Is it basically possible with only Acess ???

*I also deal with actual autoemail VB script, but without solving scheduling task it probably wont' work anyway.
Appreciate your feedback. THanks
Dai

Comment: Bingo!!! Thanks Mucho AshleeD!!!

Answer (score 1):

There's no scheduler built-in to Office specifically... but Windows has one.

Windows' **Task Scheduler** can be used to schedule code to run in Office applicationss using Office's command-line options

You should be able to find the task scheduler in the Start menu b hitting the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> and typing `task`, ***or*** by pressing       <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then typing `taskschd.msc` in the *Run* box.

There are numerous options for "how" you want to schedule your tasks.  For example I have an Access DB that auto opens every 8 hours (waking it from sleep if necessary) to perform a task, and other that runs at logon if it hasn't run in the last 12 hours.

---

### more Information:

- Office.com : [**Command-line switches for Microsoft Office products**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6)
- Office.com : [**Command-line switches for Access**](http://command-line%20switches%20for/)
  <sup>(`/x` and `/cmd` are especially useful for this.)</sup>
- Windows Dev : [**Task Scheduler**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614.aspx)

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE "D:\pathtoyourAccddbfile\file.accdb"  --- this is sample call

Answer (score 1):

I have used Task Scheduler, and similar, to open many Access DB front-ends at various frequencies from 15 minutes to a week.

It goes like this: open file, autoexec macro then opens a Form, Form_onOpen executes whatever code I want - including DoCmd actions to delete table records, create new tables, run reports, export to Excel, export as acrobat files, etc. and then save and Quit. Very useful for overnight mining SQL Server-based work management systems.

Comment: I caution you to use ‘Form Activate’ rather than ‘Form Open’ for your code container. I had many execution issues with extensive code and forms when I placed code in ‘Form Open.’